# compile time weaving and autowired on constructor

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

```
@Configurable
public TestClass(){

@Autowired SomeOtherClass otherClass;

public TestClass(Var1 var){

System.out.println(otherClass);

}


}
```

I using compile time weaving and call `new testClass(var)`.  i using dependency injection on the constructor like above "otherClass". It printed out 'null'. From my test, dependency injection 'otherClass' cannot be initialized in constructor.  what should i do to allow dependency injection on "constructor" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In support of the answer by Ralph.

From the Spring [Autowired](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) documentation.

> Fields are injected right after construction of a bean, before any config methods are invoked.

HTH

Comment: yes, i awared cannot use autowired in construcotr like you mentioned =) so, wondering any workaround

Comment: is there a particular reason that you need to act during construction, do you want to set properties or call methods for otherClass?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Note in [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) section of the Spring documentation.

It shows you the `@Configurable` attribute to use to force the injection before the code within the constructor.

```
@Configurable(preConstruction=true)
```

Adding that attribute to your code above will stop the `System.out.println(otherClass);` from being `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess (but don't know 100%) that the Autowirering take place after the object is created. (*I mean I know it for normal Spring Beans, for normal classes, but not 100% for @Configurable*)

This mean you can not expect to have an Autowired field allready populated when the object is created.

You can check this if you add an second method printStats that is invoked after creation.

```
public class TestClass {
  ...
   public void printStats(){
     System.out.println(otherClass);
   }
}

...
new TestClass(var).printStats();
```